# Get slope and curvature values at each point of a grid point using ArcMap

Tags: raster, arcmap, vector

I have DEM of a region using Slope and Curvature tool I generated raster files for slope and curvature of that region. But for my work I need slope and curvature values at each grid point (vector file) which is not available in the raster file I generated for slope and curvature.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the Question to explain how it is that we can produce data you state to be unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

[Extract Values to Points](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-values-to-points.htm) twice:

> Extracts the cell values of a raster based on a set of point features
> and records the values in the attribute table of an output feature
> class.